# Getting "Device support removed" warning while uploading App Bundle (aab) on Google Play Store

Tags: android, google-play, android-app-bundle

I'm getting following warning while uploading App Bundle (aab) to Google Play Store

> Device support removed
>
> Warning: Deactivation of this APK will result in your app being available for new installs on fewer types of devices.
>
> Tip: If this is an unintended change, then retain this APK in the new release or ensure that your new APKs support all currently supported devices.

The warning vanishes, when I build the project with assembleRelease and upload an apk file instead of building it with bundleRelease and uploading the aab file.

Is this normal for first deployment with App Bundle or should I be worried?

Comment: This isn't normal, no. This probably needs to be looked into more closely. Get in touch with the [Play Console support team](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/) to find out why your App Bundle seems to target fewer devices than your APK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't normal, the App Bundle should target exactly the same devices as the APK. This is almost certainly a bug in the tool producing the bundle. If you contact Google Play Support through the Play console they can route your query to the right people to investigate, if you are prepared to share your APK and App Bundle with Google.